# how to use multiple url variables in php echo statement

Tags: php

I was trying to execute code like one below and try to figure out what I have missed to do, but it seems bit complicated, any tips or guidance for easy way to use comma, quotes pls.

```
echo "<td><a href='update.php?jobrequestnumber$counterforlist=\".$row['jobrequestnumber'].\"&requestingcompany$counterforlist=$row['requestingcompany'].\"&dateforService$counterforlist=$row['dateforService']."'>Update</a></td>";
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the method of variable parsing in PHP, when a $ is encountered within double quotes the parser will attempt to retrieve a variable with the characters following the $.  As a result, you do not need to escape the string in order to have your variable parsed properly.  This parsing method is referred to as simple syntax.  An alternative to the simple syntax is the complex syntax which uses `{...}` to encase your variables.

In your case I would recommend using the complex syntax as it would allow for easier code maintenance/maintainability.

```
echo "<td><a href=\"update.php?jobrequestnumber{$counterforlist}={$row['jobrequestnumber']}&requestingcompany{$counterforlist}={$row['requestingcompany']}&dateforService{$counterforlist}={$row['dateforService']}\">Update</a></td>";
```

If you were using single quotes to encase your string then the following solution which utilizes the simple syntax would work:

```
echo '<td><a href="update.php?jobrequestnumber'. $counterforlist .'='. $row['jobrequestnumber'] .'&requestingcompany'. $counterforlist .'='. $row['requestingcompany'] .'&dateforService'. $counterforlist .'='. $row['dateforService'] .'">Update</a></td>';
```

There are multiple approaches to this case and you will likely find a range of answers due to the nature of this site so ultimately its up to you for which approach you wish to utilize.  Some may be more favorable than others in terms of performance, but most likely for your purposes you will not observe any noticeable differences.

Please reference the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for further explanation.

Comment: Thank you RobB, It actually works fine, I guess I need to be more aware of the defined rules for using quotes and double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be ...

```
echo "<td><a href='update.php?jobrequestnumber$counterforlist=\"".$row['jobrequestnumber']."\"&requestingcompany$counterforlist=".$row['requestingcompany']."\"&dateforService".$counterforlist."=".$row['dateforService']."'>Update</a></td>";
```

Remember you don't have to concatenate with echo just separate your arguments with a comma.
You may find this format a little easier to maintain.

```
echo '<td><a href="update.php?',
    'jobrequestnumber', $counterforlist,'=',$row['jobrequestnumber'],
    '&requestingcompany',$counterforlist,'=',$row['requestingcompany'],
    '&dateforService',$counterforlist,'=',$row['dateforService'],'">Update</a></td>"';
```

Answer (score 0):

you should know about [single and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

and your code should be like this:

```
echo "<td><a href='update.php?jobrequestnumber$counterforlist=\'.$row[jobrequestnumber].\'&requestingcompany$counterforlist=$row[requestingcompany].\'&dateforService$counterforlist=$row[dateforService].'>Update</a></td>";
```